# Salesforce Lead Capture App and Facebook Integration - Problems with FB leads syncing into Salesforce

Tags: leads, facebook

I have installed the Salesforce Labs - Facebook Lead Capture app in my org, successfully connected and created tasks.  But, bar one lead coming through when we first connected, it hasn't sent any more leads through, even though they are being created daily in FB, and my FB user is being notified.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000DrzmfUAB

Re-authorizing the tasks is shown as being successful in Salesforce.

We are not using any marketing cloud products, only Sales cloud.

Any ideas what's wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Lead capture requires a one-to-one task relationship with every Facebook ad campaign created.

So, your Facebook ad manager needs to ensure that every campaign they create, a corresponding task is created in the Salesforce Lead Capture object.